# Remap ".php!foo=bar" to "php?foor=bar" in Google App Engine PHP main.yaml

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml

I need to remap all request coming from `*.php!foo=bar` to `*.php?foo=bar`
in `Google App Eninge main.yaml`

I tried:

```
- url: /(.*)php5!(.*)$
  script: \1php5?\2
```

But it only results in errors.
The problem stems from the "?".

Even a

```
script: \1php5?foo=bar
```

does result in an error.

Comment: Suggestion for your next question on Stack : Don't just say "there's an error", copy the error. It's helpful in debugging :)

Comment: Sorry. Thanks. It says 
    Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '[...]/test.php5?foo=bar' (include_path='.:[...]/setup.php on line 147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to remap the `!(.*)` part to a query string inside of `app.yaml` because the app engine sdk treats the `script:` argument as the file to `include()` and `include("somefile.php5?foo=bar");` is only valid if the php file name contained the query string.

You could try something like this:

**app.yaml** routes all `!` requests to a single php script

```
- url: /(.*)php5!(.*)$
  script: router.php
```

**router.php** translates the `!` to a `?` then does a 301 redirect

```
<?php
$url = implode('?', explode('!', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 2));
// 301 Moved Permanently
header("Location: {$url}", true, 301);
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That's even more elegant.

Comment: PATH_INFO is only available locally though. REQUEST_URI worked on the server.

Comment: Good catch. I only checked locally.